# Why would someone want to deepcopy a function params in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, copy

I'm working on a **Node JS** project where I see a lot of costly JSON operations like `payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));`. It often appears through the project that the previous developers will just copy the input parameters from the function only to use them later as if they're references from the function's input. Here's a full example of something that I saw.

```js
process.on("assignPerson", async (payload) => {
  payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
  await agenda.schedule(
    new Date(moment().add(11, "m")),
    "sendRequest",
    payload
  );
});
```

I can't understand why this is being done. I know that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify` acts as a native js deep copy, but it's quite a costly operation. Also, not sure why anyone would want to do that. Is it because they think that the input `payload` reference will change in some other part of the program? Or is that not even possible? As I said this type of deep copying occurs through the project quite a lot. It would be great to remove it as I've heard this form of deep copying can be quite computational intensive.

Comment: The code you posted does not modify the payload argument, so it is safe to remove that. Probably the dev that wrote the function thought the function might change in the future and included it to be safe.

Comment: Looks like someone who has been burned by mutating objects in the past and has gotten over-cautious

Comment: An operation like this can prevent prototype pollution probably

Comment: Seems like the developer expected the objoect to be altered in sub-functions by reference. 
If you expect changes to your data by reference, you can also assign a new object using `payload = Object.assign({}, payload);` or `payload = {...payload}`. This is less intensive, but only required if you expect your object to be altered in another function, which is btw a bad design.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that this occurs a lot via events. Not sure if it's because this points to a common reference in which many event listeners could mutate. I do agree that this is bad design.